# Can differentiable functions be bounded like this?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If I have a function $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that is differentiable everywhere with $f$ as the derivative, and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)| dx < \infty$, does this mean there exists a function $g$ such that
$$
\left\vert\frac{F(x+h) - F(x)}{h}\right\vert \leq g(x)
$$
for all $x$ and "sufficiently small" $h$, and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)dx < \infty$? Maybe if $F$ is Lipschitz? Is there a general strategy for producing such a $g$? The context for this is trying to come up with dominating functions for using the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Seems to me the answer must be no, because the Hardy-LIttlewood maximal function is not bounded on $L^1$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich interesting, thank you. I've never heard of that function before. Would it be possible to post an answer outlining how I'd actually use it to show that the answer to my question is "no"?